# Full outer join: The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to do a full outer join in C# like this.

```
var LeftOuterJoin = from h in db.WorkingHoursPerProject
                                join t in db.Timesheets 
                                on new { IDProject = h.IDProject, Username = h.Username, Year = h.Date.Year, Month = h.Date.Month} equals
                                   new { IDProject = t.IDProject, Username = t.Username, Year = t.Date.Year, Month = t.Date.Month}
                                into temp
                                from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                select new EmployeeProjectWorkingHours {
                                    IDProject = h.IDProject,
                                    Username = h.Username,
                                    Year = h.Date.Year,
                                    Month = h.Date.Month,
                                    HoursPlanned = h.HoursPlanned ?? default(decimal),
                                    HoursSpent = t.WorkHours ?? default(decimal)
                                };

var RightOuterJoin = from t in db.Timesheets
              join h in db.WorkingHoursPerProject
                                 on new { IDProject = t.IDProject, Username = t.Username, Year = t.Date.Year, Month = t.Date.Month } equals
                                   new { IDProject = h.IDProject, Username = h.Username, Year = h.Date.Year, Month = h.Date.Month } 
                                 into temp
                                 from h in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 select new EmployeeProjectWorkingHours {
                                     IDProject = h.IDProject,
                                     Username = h.Username,
                                     Year = h.Date.Year,
                                     Month = h.Date.Month,
                                     HoursPlanned = h.HoursPlanned ?? default(decimal),
                                     HoursSpent = t.WorkHours ?? default(decimal)
                                 };

var result = LeftOuterJoin.Union(RightOuterJoin).ToList();
```

I keep getting following error:
The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Non of the int properties are nullable. Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: I haven't read your query, but if it's an outer join I'd guess that sometimes a matching row isn't found, so the result from the database for that column is `null`. [This question might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36562565/linq-the-cast-to-value-type-system-int32-failed-because-the-materialized-valu) although I don't use Entity Framework / LINQ query syntax so I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you are returning a value type, and that value might be missing, you need to cast it to Nullable for linq / entity framework to return the right value. eg `IDProject = (int?)h.IDProject`

Answer (score 0):

In the second query you are using in select new EmployeeProjectWorkingHours 
h that is from DefaultIfEmpty. What happen is h is empty? therefore i think so that IDProject, Username, Year, Month must asigned value from t not from h.